# Polymer iron-form multipart/form-data support

Tags: forms, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to get image submission working inside an `iron-form` and am running into some difficulties. Here's a minimized version of the form:

```
<dom-module id="file-upload">
    <template>
        <form is="iron-form" id="form" content-type="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:9090/upload" method="post">  
            <input name="field-1" type="file" accept="image/*" required><br>
            <paper-button on-tap="submit">submit</paper-button>
        </form>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "file-upload",
        submit: function() {
            this.$.form.submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I try to send the file over to my Go server, I get this error:

`no multipart boundary param in Content-Type`

I already got a regular form working properly, so I know it isn't an issue with my server, but I want to use all of the fancy Polymer elements for other fields that will be added to the form. Is anyone aware if `multipart/form-data` is currently unsupported as a content-type?

I could create a regular form which contains Polymer elements which bind to hidden inputs, but it seems like a gross hack that I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this element: [ajax-file-input](https://github.com/liuyang1204/ajax-file-input)

It works for me, for PHP backend $_FILES is containing the upload data.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Polymer 1.0, and this is a Polymer 0.5 element. I also want to eventually include other inputs in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently unsupported.  There was an open issue about this a couple of years ago, with some suggestions on how to work around here: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/issues/54#issuecomment-156966362